# How to calculate X Y from an angle?

Tags: c#, math, position

From an angle I'm trying to get the X and Y position;

Position X is working correctly, but Y position is reversed. Negative when positive, positive when negative.

Angle: 270 °

**Correct: X: 0 Y: 1**

Code:

```
double angle = 270 * Math.PI / 180;

double x = Math.Cos(angle);
double y = Math.Sin(angle);
```

**Result: X: 0 Y: -1**

> In addition to the correction I would like to understand the reason.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What makes X: 0, Y: 1 "correct" in your view? Normal trigonometry measures angles counter-clockwise from the positive X-axis... The point (1, 0) rotated 270 degrees anticlockwise around the origin is (0, -1) as per the result you're getting.

Comment: to understand how sine and cosine are computed and why the result calculated by your computer is correct please read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)

Comment: If you want your angles to move CLOCKWISE from the positive x-axis, simply multiply them by -1.